# Get WooCommerce orders Items by variation ID

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

How can I list order items based on a specific product variations?

Given a **variation ID**, I would like to generate a list of all **order items** that include that particular variation.

In my case I'm using variations to represent dates and the product itself is a recurring event, so the purpose of this is to list the people attending that specific date.

It would be amazing if this could be accomplished by something simple like a `get_posts` using `meta_keys` or something in that vein, but otherwise I'm guessing a custom query would be the way.

I just can't seem to figure out how the tables relate in this case or if this is stored in a searchable way.

Any help very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is many ways to accomplish that. Here I use in a custom function with one SQL query and a **`$variation_id`** *(the variation ID to set in)* as parameter in it:

```
function get_all_orders_items_from_a_product_variation( $variation_id ){

    global $wpdb;

    // Getting all Order Items with that variation ID
    $item_ids_arr = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT `order_item_id` 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta 
        WHERE meta_key LIKE '_variation_id' 
        AND meta_value = %s
    ", $variation_id ) );

    return $item_ids_arr; // return the array of orders items ids

}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**USAGE** *(here with the variation ID 41 for example)*:

This will display a list of orders items IDs for this variation ID with some data (for example).

```
$items_ids = get_all_orders_items_from_a_product_variation( 41 );

// Iterating through each order item
foreach( $items_ids as $item_id ){

    // Getting some data (the color value here)
    $item_color = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'pa_color', true );

    // Displaying some data related to the current order item
    echo 'Item ID: '. $item_id . ' with color "' . $item_color .'"<br>';
}
```

This code is tested and works.

---

> **GETTING THE ORDER ID** *(UPDATED)*

Now if you need to get all the Orders IDs instead, you can use another query inside that function this way:

```
function get_all_orders_that_have_a_product_variation( $variation_id ){

    global $wpdb;

    // Getting all Order IDs with that variation ID
    $order_ids_arr = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT DISTINCT items.order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS items
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS itemmeta ON items.order_item_id = itemmeta.order_item_id
        WHERE meta_key LIKE '_variation_id'
        AND meta_value = %s
    ", $variation_id ) );

    return $order_ids_arr; // return the array of orders ids

}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**USAGE** *(here always with the variation ID 41 for example)*:

This will display a list of orders IDs for this variation ID with their status (for example).

```
$orders_ids = get_all_orders_that_have_a_product_variation( 41 );

// Iterating through each order item
foreach( $orders_ids as $order_id ){

    // Getting an instance of the order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Displaying some data related to the current order
    echo 'Order #'. $order_id . ' has status "' . $order->get_status() .'"<br>';
}
```

This code is tested and works.

> You can also combine in a more complex array, the Order ID with it's related Items IDs in a multi-dimensional array this way:

```
function get_all_orders_and_item_ids_that_have_a_product_variation( $variation_id ){

    global $wpdb;

    // Getting all Order IDs and item ids with that variation ID
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT items.order_id, items.order_item_id AS item_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS items
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS itemmeta ON items.order_item_id = itemmeta.order_item_id
        WHERE meta_key LIKE '_variation_id'
        AND meta_value = %s
    ", $variation_id ), ARRAY_A );

    return $results; // return a multi-dimensional array of orders Ids / items Ids

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough answer! I ended up using a combination of your second function and WC functions to flesh out the data, but will investigate whether I can optimise but getting all from the query.

Comment: Not working for me, Could be a version issue? Getting blank array only.

Comment: I tried to add get order ids, used second function with custom prefix only but no luck. It's just showing blank array. Even tried to check function then found `item_ids_arr` is showing blank array.

Comment: Should I create a new question with my code? I have two variations namely "S" & "L". I just want the orders id of both so that I can count the number of orders for a particular variation.

Comment: @BilalHussain I finally found the problem in the 2nd function *(sorry)*. So code is updated and works in a unique SQL query (instead of 2). It will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the same, after looking at db I was getting `0` in front of `'_variation_id'`. But got the orders items using my custom hack for the future people who are looking for the same issue. We need to compare using `product_name`, `variaion_name` such as Size etc. And `variation_value` LIKE 'S', 'L' etc. Consider this function:

```
function get_all_orders_that_have_a_product_variation( $product_name, $variation_name, $variation_value ){

global $wpdb;
// Getting all Order IDs with that variation ID

$order_ids_arr = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare ( "
        SELECT * FROM wpcc_woocommerce_order_items items 
        LEFT JOIN wpcc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta itemmeta ON items.order_item_id = itemmeta.order_item_id 
        WHERE items.order_item_name LIKE %s 
        AND itemmeta.meta_key LIKE %s 
        AND itemmeta.meta_value = %s", $product_name, $variation_name, $variation_value ));


 return $order_ids_arr; // return the array of orders ids

}
```

Now call it, say our product name is `Raleigh sport`, variation name is `size` and value is `s`. In simple form, we want to get the order items id of the product whose name is `Raleigh sport` and we want to fetch only whose `size` is `S`

simple call by function:

`print_r(get_all_orders_that_have_a_product_variation( "Raleigh Sport", "Size", "S" ));`

thanks.