# Sort Orders IDs alphabetically based on the shipping last name in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I need to sort my $order_name (more specifically $order_shipping_last_name) alphabetically. I've tried many different basic php sort() methods, in many different places, and can't get this to work. I'm assuming I'm missing something?

In my code, `get_all_orders_that_have_a_product_variation( $product_id );` function comes from [**this answer code**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42546498) that allow to get an array of **orders IDs** from a variation ID…

The list is output as `$variables['order_list']` near the bottom.

```
add_action( 'fue_before_variable_replacements', 'w_add_stuff', 10, 4);
function w_add_stuff( $var, $email_data, $fue_email, $queue_item ) {

    $product_id = 2339; 
    $orders_ids = get_all_orders_that_have_a_product_variation( $product_id );

    // Iterating through each order
    foreach( $orders_ids as $order_id ){

        // Name Data
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $order_data = $order->get_data();  
        $order_shipping_first_name = $order_data['shipping']['first_name'];
        $order_shipping_last_name = $order_data['shipping']['last_name'];
        $order_name = $order_shipping_last_name . ',' . ' ' . $order_shipping_first_name . ' ';

        // Iterating through each order item
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values){

            //Quantity Data   
            $item_data = $item_values->get_data();
            $variation_id = $item_data['variation_id'];
            $item_quantity = $item_data['quantity'];

            // Display name and quantity of specific variation only
            if ( $variation_id == $product_id ) {
                $variables['order_list'] .= $order_name . ' ' . '...' . ' ' . $item_quantity . '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you find out when you stepped through your code with the debugger? And when you sprinkled `error_log()` calls around to see what's going on? Also, carve out a working example of your code that demonstrates the problem, so people can experiment with it. But before you go to that much trouble, talk about your debugger and `error_log()` results. (Not to me, but edit your question with the results, so everyone can see without reading through the comments.)

Comment: What's up with this stuff `**$stuff....;**` ?  Last I knew `**` was  Exponentiation  Like  `2^10` in math.  Besides I don't see `sort` in there at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be done before in the function **where you get the Orders IDs**, changing a bit the included SQL query, this way:

```
function get_all_orders_that_have_a_product_variation( $variation_id ){
    global $wpdb;

    // Getting all Order IDs with that variation ID
    $order_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT DISTINCT woi.order_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON woi.order_id = pm.post_id
        WHERE woim.meta_key LIKE '_variation_id'
        AND woim.meta_value = '$variation_id'
        AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_shipping_last_name'
        ORDER BY pm.meta_value ASC
    " );

    return $order_ids; // return the array of orders ids
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)*. Tested and works.

> The change is made on **sorting the Orders IDs** array using **the shipping last name.**